# I try to install moviepy external module in the terminal but something is wrong

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, pip, moviepy

I have a problem. I tried to install moviepy in the terminal in the Visual Studio Code (moviepy is an external module). But something is wrong and I dont't what. Here is a screen with terminal error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOekq.png)

I tried to install moviepy in the terminal in the Visual Studio Code and I were expecting that moviepy will install without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Errno 13] Permission denied

You can use the following way to give vscode administrator privileges.

[image]

1. Right click vscode and choose properties.
2. Click compatibility and check "Run this program as an administrator" then apply.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO

The file permissions are preventing your current user to install it, and as described in the error message you can reach it by adding `--user <username>` to your command, when `<username>` is the one owning the `decorator.py` file.

Run `ls -l /path/to/decorator.py` to find out the username.

You can try prefixing your command with `sudo` to run as the root user that probably has permission, but usually, that's overkill and unrecommended.

Comment: If i try to run: ls -l /path/to/decorator.py i have an error which say that this path doesn't exists.